# JWT Login Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I' m trying to create login view with djangorestframework-jwt.When i logged my user (url 'login/') it was fine and everything worked but and switched to another page (url 'post_list') to create a post I got an error that my user is anonymous so that is why I decided that that my user is again unauthenticated. Could you please help me to create proper JWT Login view that will allow me to create and switch between different pages without any obstacles?

My settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
}
```

My Serializers:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,
                                     required=True,
                                     style={
                                         'input_type': 'password',
                                         'placeholder': 'password'
                                     })


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

My views:

```
class UserLogin(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    POST login/
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TokenSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get("username", "")
        password = request.data.get("password", "")

        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return Response({
                "token": jwt_encode_handler(jwt_payload_handler(user)),
                'username': username,
            }, status=200)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


class PostView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
        POST, GET post_list/
    """

    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', UserRegistration.as_view(), name='registration'),
    url(r'^login/$', UserLogin.as_view(), name='user_login'),
    url(r'^post_list/$', PostView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
]
```

Comment: After loggging in, do you send your jwt token in the request authorization header while trying to create a post?

Comment: What are you using as your front end framework? As the above commentator noted, you need to provide an 'Authorization' header with every request to an authenticated endpoint for your backend. The header will have the token in it you receive at login.

Comment: @Nida I am using djangorestframework

Comment: @roziukp DRF is your backend. Which language are you writing the website / client code on? Usually something like Angular, React or even pure JavaScript

Comment: Please, provide how do you send both requests